# 404 error when configuring SVN on Amazon EC2

Tags: svn, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache

I am trying to set up an SVN server on an existing EC2 instance. My idea is to have the repository on S3, i.e., I wish to make the SVN server point to the repository bucket on S3. These are the steps I performed:

1. Add a rule to the EC2 security group to allow TCP access on port 80
   from 0.0.0.0/0
2. SSH into the EC2 instance.
3. Install subversion

   ```
       yum install subversion
   ```
4. Install Apache 2 (I verified that the httpd package was already installed)
5. Install mod_dav_svn

   ```
       yum install mod_dav_svn
   ```
6. Add the following line in the httpd.conf file:

   ```
       LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
       ...
       <Location /svn>
           DAV svn
           SVNPath http://gyanify-svn.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
       </Location>
   ```
7. Restart the apache web server

   ```
    sudo apachectl restart
   ```

However, after doing the above, I notice a couple of things:

1. Running

   ```
   sudo apachectl status
   ```

   gives a 404 error

   ```
   HTTP Status 404 -
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      type Status report
      message
      description The requested resource is not available.
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
   ```
2. Running

   ```
   sudo apachectl restart
   ```

   gives the following:

   ```
   [Sun Dec 09 21:26:02 2012] [warn] module dav_svn_module is already loaded, skipping
   ```

Additional details that may/may not help:

- I already have a web application deployed on the EC2 instance using
  Elastic Beanstalk and it is working fine.
- I am using the default Amazon Linux AMI

Can someone advise what I'm missing here or what I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in this manner.  `SVNPath` is supposed to point to a local file path, not a URL.

You can try to mount your S3 bucket using a loopback mount with [S3backer](http://code.google.com/p/s3backer/).  I'm not sure I'd use something like this in production though.  Make sure that you're getting solid backups of your repo.

Comment: Thank you, that was the perfect answer for my needs.